# Cannot use Add-Migration in RapidBlazor clean architecture EF 7.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, blazor

With https://github.com/jasontaylordev/RapidBlazor template
I'm trying to extend ApplicationUser class by adding additional parameters.

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string? MoreInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I run Add-Migration or I try Update-Database, I'm getting

```
*System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
2\> ---\> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid column name 'MoreInfo'.)
2\> ---\> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'MoreInfo'.
2\>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.\<\>c.\<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync\>b__208_0(Task\`1 result)*
```

Build Succeeded shows only, when I create columns in the database first.
I cannot create new table too....

How to change this template or resolve this problem?